# Plot a normal distribution in R with specific parameters

Tags: r, plot, parameters, probability-density

I'd like to plot something like this:

```
plot(dnorm(mean=2),from=-3,to=3)
```

But it doesn't work as if you do:

```
plot(dnorm,from=-3,to=3)
```

what is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer you received from @r2evans is excellent. You might also want to consider learning `ggplot`, as in the long run it will likely make your life much easier. In that case, you can use `stat_function` which will plot the results of an arbitrary function along a grid of the x variable. It accepts arguments to the function as a list.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = data.frame(x=c(-3,3)), aes(x = x)) + 
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = 2))
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to extend this to a 3D plot?

Answer (score 4):

```r
curve(dnorm(x, mean = 2), from = -3, to = 3)
```

[image: normal plot]

The `curve` function looks for the `xname=` variable (defaults to `x`) in the function *call*, so in `dnorm(x, mean=2)`, it is not referencing an `x` in the calling environment, it is a placeholder for `curve` to use for iterated values.

The reason `plot(dnorm, ...)` works as it does is because there exists `graphics::plot.function`, since `dnorm` in that case is a function. When you try `plot(dnorm(mean=2))`, the `dnorm(mean=2)` is no longer a function, it is a call ... that happens to fail because it requires `x` (its first argument) be provided.

Incidentally, `plot.function` calls `curve(...)`, so other than being a convenience function, there is very little reason to use `plot(dnorm, ...)` over `curve(dnorm(x), ...)` other than perhaps a little code-golf. The biggest advantage to `curve` is that it lets you control arbitrary arguments to the `dnorm()` function, whereas `plot.function` does not.